# test the difference between two samples AND also control for other variables

Tags: analysis

I would like to test whether there are any difference in performance between two groups of samples  $A$ ($100$ observation) and $B$ ($140$ observation),  but at the same time, I would want to control for their differences in characteristics, for e.g. age, size etc.  How do I go about doing that?  I tried to regress $A$ on $B$ and the characteristics...but the results are weird.  Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Are the two samples from the same population?

Comment: yes there are from the same population...

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to test whether the characteristics of age, size are different in both populations is to do an ANOVA, and see whether the paired factors are different or not (this is the extension of the test of difference of means of the same parameter to differences of means of many different parameters). If the test is negative, you can do additional tests to decide which of the factors are different from each other.

If it was possible to start anew collecting data, you could try to collect data from within subpopulations that have the same age, size, that way you know that these are held constant, so controlled for.

Comment: sounds interesting! i suppose this is a one way anova? and i do one for sample A and one for sample B? or there is actually a way to do both together?

Comment: I would think you do one for both, because you are testing the characteristics from within the same population.

Comment: ok thanks!.. so how about the performance of sample A and B ? i wont be able to test for their performance differences at the same time through one way anova right...?

Comment: I would say that if ANOVA is not rejected, i.e., if the two traits have the same mean, then you can do a standard difference of means test. If ANOVA is rejected, i.e. if the paired traits have different values, then it is harder, let me think.